# Change content of a zip file with Abbrevia

Tags: delphi, zip, abbrevia

I have a existing zip archive and want to change a file which is already in the zipfile. Furthermore I want to add an file to the existing zip archive. I tried with TZipFile but it doesn't offer the required functionality. But Abbrevia should be able to but I don't know how.

```
coZip := TAbZipper.Create(nil);

coZip.OpenArchive(ContainerFileName);

coZip.ChangeFile(xxx); // What to do here? ChangeFile or similar function does not exist

coZip.AddFiles("NewFile.txt");
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Unrelated to any framework was the idea of ZIP archives to mark existing entries as deleted and add a new entry instead of rebuilding the whole ZIP file and actually removing entries. https://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/files/Documentation/3.04/tpabbrevia_docs.zip/download mentions AddFiles() and DeleteFiles() in TAbZipOutline.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using TZipFile with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164299/delphi-xe2-tzipfile-replace-a-file-in-zip-archive

Comment: That link is a question - you probably mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/13165888/4299358